# Where to change data for a "list" datasource in dashcode?

Tags: iphone, dashcode

I created a new project in dashcode and it automatically generated a mobile web app for me with a list and sample datasources. I see two datasources, one is labeled as "datasource" and the other is "list". However I can see that the actual data in datasources is in a js file, everything is good but where is the actual data stored for "list"?

The sample application came with a bunch of data for "list" and I am unable to change it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on "DataSource" under Data Sources, you'll notice that the top line displayed is URL. It is assumed that the DataSource you'll be using is on the web somewhere (there's a way to maintain the datasource locally on the iphone but I'll get to that in a minute). So, "publish" you xml|rss|atom|etc. data on a web site somewhere and enter the appropriate URL. When you press return or hit the refresh arrow, if the URL is correct, DashCode will parse your data file and the DataSource and List items will reflect your xml structure).

Then using DashCode create the bindings between your data and your DashCode template.... I whiz right by this because there is an excellent tutorial at the apple developer website at: http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004692-CH1-SW1

If the above link fails, go to "developer.apple.com" and from that home page search for "DashCode". The intro document should be the first link returned.

This intro walks you through writing DashCode applications including working with DataSources and binding to your templates.

Comment: BlueJ, in your answer, you promise "there's a way to maintain the datasource locally on the iphone but I'll get to that in a minute" but do not fulfill your promise! How do you do this? I am actually interested in doing this within OSX--not iOS. Although I am able to bind a list to an XML file that is imported into the widget bundle folder, I am unable to bind to this XML file when its external to the bundle folder--e.g. on the desktop.